# Select data from DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
ltab_vals DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
  v_tablen BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN

DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(list   => 'AA,B,CC,DEF'
                              ,tablen => v_tablen
                              ,tab    => ltab_vals);

END;
/
```

How to use ltab_vals variable in select statement?
I need to write something like this:

```
SELECT val INTO variable_ FROM v_tablen WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only use SQL types in SQL statements. so you have to convert that PL/SQL array into a SQL one.

for example if we create a `your_array` type.

```
SQL> create table your_table(col varchar2(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into your_table values ('AA');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into your_table values ('DEF');

1 row created.

SQL> create type your_array as table of varchar2(4000);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2  ltab_vals DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
  3    v_tablen BINARY_INTEGER;
  4     v_t your_array := your_array();
  5  BEGIN
  6
  7    DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(list   => 'AA,B,CC,DEF'
  8                                ,tablen => v_tablen
  9                                ,tab    => ltab_vals);
```

copy the array over to an SQL one:

```
 10    for idx in 1..ltab_vals.count
 11    loop
 12      v_t.extend;
 13      v_t(v_t.last) := ltab_vals(idx);
 14    end loop;
 15
```

now form the select using the `table()` function. The cardinality hint should be a reasonable guess on the number of elements in the array. without this hint, you may find that oracle picks a worse plan (as by default, it will assume ~8k rows in the array).

```
 17    for r_row in (select /*+ cardinality(p, 10) */ t.*
 18                    from your_table t
 19                         inner join table(v_t) p
 20                                 on t.col = p.column_value)
 21    loop
 22      dbms_output.put_line(r_row.col);
 23    end loop;
 24
 25  END;
 26  /
AA
DEF

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```